# "Cannot resolve symbol 'androidmads"

Tags: android-studio

[image]I have a problem about importing "androidmads.library.qrgenearator.QRGContents;" , it says "Cannot resolve symbol 'androidmads" even that i've already implements the following inside defendenc[image]

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue you did. Two Steps to solve this:

1. Go into Gradle Scripts -> settings.gradle and add maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
   [settings.gradle file image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wISbm.png)
2. Go into Gradle Scripts -> build.gradle(Module:XXXXX) and add "implementation 'com.github.androidmads:QRGenerator:1.0.1'"
   [implementation addition image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XlcOY.png)

I hope this helps you if you're still having this issue and also anyone who comes across this post.